# create activity_instance for Eventlogs

Tags: python, r, csv, uuid, event-log

I got a CSV file that look like this:

[image]

what i want to get is this:

[image]

the activity instance is needed to identifiy which events belong together and which not. this instance identifier should be unique, also among different cases and activities.
I have no idea how to generate those ID's. Is there any library for example in python who could handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R you could try the following using `dplyr`.

Using `arrange` you can ensure your data is by `patient` and in chronological order. Then the `activity_instance` will be a number incremented when the `patient` or `activity` changes going from row to row.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(patient, timestamp) %>%
  mutate(activity_instance = 1 + cumsum(
    (patient != lag(patient, default = first(patient)) |
     activity != lag(activity, default = first(activity)))))
```